# how to disable table property in adf table

Tags: oracle-adf

I am getting below exception when trying to disable the adf table in on click event.
Caused By: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: View.disabled() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [attribute]

I am  using the following approach .
i have set the disable property in View also set the custom property in view.

disabled="#{row.bindings.attribute.hints.disabled}"

if any one had faced this issue then please suggest how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should just work in your UI layer for this use case.
Set the disabled property of the item to be based on a value in a managed bean, and switch that value in your click event listener.

Answer (score 0):

adf tables don't have disable properties.
If you have to disable columns you have set it in each attributes with conditions on jsf page or backing bean.

it is bit lengthy but you won't have any scope rather than this.